# Why ID selector takes advantage on class selector?

Tags: css, css-specificity

Given one element with a class and ID ; if I apply some CSS with a class selector to an element, and override it with some CSS with an ID selector, the later is applied.

```
 <a class='abc' id='def' href="#"></a>
 <style>
 .abc{
   color:red;
 }
 #def{
   color:blue;
 }
 </style>
```

Why ID selector takes advantage on class selector?

Comment: ID returns only one element, so search stops after ID is found. Multiple elements can have same class, so search continues till the end of DOM

Comment: What you're really asking isn't related to jQuery at all, it's just CSS specificity

Comment: But I have one class and one ID

Comment: Thanks for answers, I have one more doubt, why is it taking id's color??

Comment: You have two completely unrelated questions here. Please make up your mind which one you're asking.

Comment: Sorry... But please tell me  why is it taking id's color??

Answer (score 2):

> if i am giving same style to class and same style to Id why its take
>   ID Style

That has nothing to do with jQuery, and everything to do with [CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.

In other words, certain selectors have higher priority than others, in this order

1. Inline style
2. ID selectors
3. Class selectors, Pseudo-classes, Attributes selectors
4. Universal selectors

Note that applying styles to ID's will be more specific than applying styles to classes, and hence override other styles, and inline styles will override styles set in an external stylesheet.

If the specificity is the same, the order of the styles will determine what styles are used, latter being applied over former etc.

Comment: And a small example of idea: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccrv3cuh/1/).

Comment: There is no priority of pseudo-classes over attributes over class. They all have the same priority.

Comment: @Alohci: You'll have the MDN contributors to blame for that one. I wonder how many readers have been misled by that article, and when anybody is going to step in and fix it. (I say this fully aware that [I'm part of the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect)...)

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code doesn't include any jQuery/javascript at all, so one way to interpret the question is in terms of CSS only.

But for the sake of answering this in terms of jQuery/javascript, you have to think in terms of cross-browser compatibility.

Using an ID selector in jQuery basically translates to the vanilla-javascript `document.getElementByID`, which is pretty much universal.

Using a CSS class selector in jQuery, however, ideally translates to the vanilla-javascript `document.getElementsByClassName`.

But actually it may be doing more than you think.

For example, if you check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname, you can see that IE8 does not fully support getElementsbyClassName().

jQuery's job here is to make these browser differences transparent.

In short, the more complex your selector is, the higher chance jQuery needs to tackle cross-browser differences.